# How to work with multiple URL's for same site in multi-site Wagtail environment

Tags: wagtail

I'm setting up a multi-site environment with Wagtail (perhaps a bit ambitious as I'm new to Wagtail, Django and Python, but I would like to migrate some simple sites to Wagtail and wanted to have the correct setup from the beginning). 
I have created a list of sites in the Wagtail admin and the home pages for each of the sites.
I would like some of the site to be reachable through multiple URL's (name.com + name.othername.com). 
Should I create a new site setting (through "Add Site" in the admin) for each URL, or is there a better/different way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use an external web server (eg. Apache) to work with multiple domains. Define a virtual host proxy to point to your wagtail app.

Here is an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
    ServerAlias example2.com

    # Here we define the proxy to your wagtail app
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    # Reverse Proxy for load balancing
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
    # Preserves the host if you use docker
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

You will need an external web server anyway to serve static content in non-debug mode.

Comment: I use NGINX and I have arranged the coverage of the different URL's in my NGINX setup, but shouldn't Wagtail understand the URL's too? And I understood that in a multi-site setup I need to tell Wagtail what the homepages of the different URL(s) are.

Comment: As long as all your pages have the same website entry point, it's enough to define one wagtail site and several nginx proxys pointing to it. Wagtail doesn't care about the hostname of the virtual host.

If you want to use different entry points for different pages, create several wagtail sites. The hostname and the port should match your virtual host configuration. You may define several proxies, one for each wagtail site. Then run a separate wagtail instances for each port with: `./manage.py runserver <port>`

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tobias! But...I'm using the multi-site setup; more or less as described here: https://wagtail.io/blog/multi-site-wagtail. So I defined the URL's and entry points (pages to be used) for the different sites in the Sites menu and defined those (entry point) pages below the root level. So far so good. I assume that I need to define alternative/alias URL's (www.a.com as alternative/alias for a.com for example) also in the Sites menu. Sounds correct to you?

Comment: Your title is misleading, as you want 1 site to be reachable under multiple domains. Instead you talk about a multi-site, which is 2 or more sites, on one installation, that is (also) reachable through 2 or more domains. An alias at webserver level would be the way to go, not adding multiple sites to one wagtail install.